# Delphi 11, Android, directory file list

Tags: android, delphi

I'm trying to get a directory files list in order to have a list and, later, choose one under android and delphi 11.0.
After severals long search (here) and unsuccessful tries at the end i found this post.

[Delphi Rio fails to read external storage with READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53579965/delphi-rio-fails-to-read-external-storage-with-read-external-storage-permissions)

Where Dalija gave this code:

```
uses
  System.Permissions,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.App,
  Androidapi.JNI.OS,
  ...

procedure TMainForm.AddFiles;
var
  LFiles: TArray<string>;
  LFile: string;
begin
  LFiles := TDirectory.GetFiles(TPath.GetSharedDownloadsPath);
  for LFile in LFiles do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(LFile);
    end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)],
    procedure(const APermissions: TArray<string>; const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>)
    begin
      if (Length(AGrantResults) = 1) and (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add('GRANTED');
          AddFiles;
        end
      else
        begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add('NOT GRANTED');
        end;
    end)
```

This code works great under delphi 10.4 update 2 but not under delphi 11.0

Why ??

I'm not able to run it on 11.0 (with new procedure's syntax, i.e `APermissions: TArray<string>` in delphi 10.4 now is `APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray` in delphi 11)

Thank's for any help

Daniele

Comment: "*I'm not able to run it on 11.0*" - why not? What is the actual problem? Do you get a compiler error? A runtime error? Bad results? You need to be more specific.

Comment: On a side note, you should call `PermissionsService.IsPermissionGranted()` before you call `PermissionsService.RequestPermissions()`. No need to request permissions if you already have them.

Comment: @Remy:The main problem is that all seems to go in a rigth way... The code (Dalija code) is compiled without any error but when it run on a device (in my case Samsung S10+ with last android 12)  LFile is empty no result. Back to delphi 10.4 the LFile contains the file list. More, i can't debug because, without any reasons, F9 stop to work! The brackpoint does not work anymore.... but this is another problem

Comment: `LFile` (singular) is an element of `LFiles` (plural). I can't imagine `GetFiles()` returning an array of blank strings. So, did you mean that `LFiles` is empty instead? Did you check that `GetSharedDownloadsPath` is returning a correct path?

Comment: Remy thank's for your reply. This is the matter ..... same code different enviroments (delphi 10.4 and 11) different result. Under 10.4 i got the file list, under 11 (chanching TArray<string> with TClassicStringDynArray and others changes) in same directory (TPath.GetSharedDownloadsPath and return same path as delphi10.4) the list is empty. I'm going crazy but .... i continue to search a way out. !!!

Comment: You did not answer my question - is it really `LFile` *inside the loop* that is empty, or is it really `LFiles` *outside the loop* that is empty? Is `GetFiles()` returning an array whose length is 0, or is it returning an array whose length is > 0 but the strings are empty? There is a big difference.

Comment: Hi Remy, excuse me .... i thougth to answer you (The list is empty). The array (LFiles) is empty (IntToStr(High(LFiles) return always, for any directory, -1) using delphi 11; Same code with Delphi 10.4.2 return a number (files present into a directory (any) ). I'll try on a pc where is installed delphi 11.1 To be Honest i do not understand what happend in delphi 11. Thank you for your help ....

Comment: In that case, assuming you have adequate permissions to access the folder, then this sounds like a regression that should be [reported to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Answer (score 2):

Embarcadero changed the function signatures with the release of Delphi 11. This will get you started with sorting that out.

```
{$if COMPILERVERSION > 34}
  {$define NEW_ALEX}
{$else}
  {$if COMPILERVERSION > 32}
    {$define NEW_RIO}
  {$endif}
{$endif}

  private
    FPermittoVibrate: Boolean;
    FVibratePermission: String;
    FPermitAccessFineLocation: Boolean;
    FAccessFineLocation: String;
    FPermitNetworkState: Boolean;
    FNetworkStatePermission: String;
    FPermitWifiState: Boolean;
    FWifiStatePermission: String;
    FPermitPhoneState: Boolean;
    FPhoneStatePermission: String;

  {$ifdef NEW_RIO}
  procedure PermissionResult(Sender: TObject;
    const APermissions: TArray<string>;
    const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
  procedure PermissionRequest(Sender: TObject;
    const APermissions: TArray<string>;
    const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
  {$endif}
  {$ifdef NEW_ALEX}
  procedure PermissionsResult(Sender: TObject;
    const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray;
    const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray
  );
  procedure DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject;
    const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray;
    const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
  {$endif}

{$ifdef NEW_RIO}
if TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.SDK_INT >= 23 then // 6 or higher
begin
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([
      FVibratePermission
    , FAccessFineLocation
    , FNetworkStatePermission
    , FWifiStatePermission
    , FPhoneStatePermission
    ],
    PermissionResult, PermissionRequest
    );
end;
{$endif}
{$ifdef NEW_ALEX}
if TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.SDK_INT >= 23 then // 6 or higher
begin
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([
      FVibratePermission
    , FAccessFineLocation
    , FNetworkStatePermission
    , FWifiStatePermission
    , FPhoneStatePermission
    ],
    PermissionsResult, DisplayRationale
    );
end;
{$endif}

{$ifdef NEW_RIO}

procedure TfrmMain.PermissionRequest(Sender: TObject;
  const APermissions: TArray<string>; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
var
  I: Integer;
  RationaleMsg: string;
begin
  RationaleMsg := 'The app needs ';
  for I := 0 to High(APermissions) do
  begin
    if APermissions[I] = FVibratePermission then
      RationaleMsg := RationaleMsg + 'to vibrate the phone' + linefeed;
    if APermissions[I] = FAccessFineLocation then
      RationaleMsg := RationaleMsg + linefeed + 'to access fine location';
    if APermissions[I] = FNetworkStatePermission then
      RationaleMsg := RationaleMsg + linefeed + 'to access network state';
    if APermissions[I] = FWifiStatePermission then
      RationaleMsg := RationaleMsg + linefeed + 'to access wifi state';
    if APermissions[I] = FPhoneStatePermission then
      RationaleMsg := RationaleMsg + linefeed + 'to read phone state';
  end;
  TDialogService.ShowMessage(RationaleMsg,
    procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      APostRationaleProc;
    end)
end;

procedure TfrmMain.PermissionResult(Sender: TObject;
  const APermissions: TArray<string>;
  const AGrantResults: TArray<TPermissionStatus>);
var
  Permission: String;
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(APermissions) do
  begin
    Permission := APermissions[i];
    if Permission = FVibratePermission then
      FPermitToVibrate := AGrantResults[i] = TPermissionStatus.Granted
    else if Permission = FAccessFineLocation then
      FPermitAccessFineLocation := AGrantResults[i] = TPermissionStatus.Granted
    else if Permission = FNetworkStatePermission then
      FPermitNetworkState := AGrantResults[i] = TPermissionStatus.Granted
    else if Permission = FWifiStatepermission then
      FPermitWifiState := AGrantResults[i] = TPermissionStatus.Granted
    else if Permission = FPhoneStatePermission then
      FPermitPhoneState := AGrantResults[i] = TPermissionStatus.Granted
      ;
  end;

end;

{$endif NEW_RIO}

{$ifdef NEW_ALEX}

procedure TfrmMain.PermissionsResult(Sender: TObject;
  const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray;
  const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray
);
var
  Permission: String;
  i: Integer;
begin

  for i := 0 to High(APermissions) do
  begin
    Permission := APermissions[i];
    if Permission = FVibratePermission then
      FPermitToVibrate := AGrantResults[i] = TPermissionStatus.Granted
    else if Permission = FAccessFineLocation then
      FPermitAccessFineLocation := AGrantResults[i] = TPermissionStatus.Granted
    else if Permission = FNetworkStatePermission then
      FPermitNetworkState := AGrantResults[i] = TPermissionStatus.Granted
    else if Permission = FWifiStatepermission then
      FPermitWifiState := AGrantResults[i] = TPermissionStatus.Granted
    else if Permission = FPhoneStatePermission then
      FPermitPhoneState := AGrantResults[i] = TPermissionStatus.Granted
  end;

end;

procedure TfrmMain.DisplayRationale(Sender: TObject;
  const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray;
  const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
var
  I: Integer;
  RationaleMsg: string;
begin
  RationaleMsg := 'The app needs ';
  for I := 0 to High(APermissions) do
  begin
    if APermissions[I] = FVibratePermission then
      RationaleMsg := RationaleMsg + 'to vibrate the phone' + SLineBreak;
    if APermissions[I] = FAccessFineLocation then
      RationaleMsg := RationaleMsg + SLineBreak + 'to access fine location';
    if APermissions[I] = FNetworkStatePermission then
      RationaleMsg := RationaleMsg + SLineBreak + 'to access network state';
    if APermissions[I] = FWifiStatePermission then
      RationaleMsg := RationaleMsg + SLineBreak + 'to access wifi state';
    if APermissions[I] = FPhoneStatePermission then
      RationaleMsg := RationaleMsg + SLineBreak + 'to read phone state';
  end;
  TDialogService.ShowMessage(RationaleMsg,
    procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      APostRationaleProc;
    end)
end;

{$endif NEW_ALEX}
```

Comment: Thank's Freddie, i'll try your suggestion. As i wrote to Remy (under delphii 11) the problem i have is how i have not back the file list (in LFile) while i have under 10.4. Due the fact the code (in both ides with rigth code) is compiled without errors, it is very problably (under 11) i have some permission problem or manifest token missing .... I have to do some more work to understand....

Comment: @FreddieBell The code you have shown is needlessly duplicating a LOT of code just to account for a couple of changed types.  You should be able to avoid all of that duplication by simply declaring a couple of type aliases for pre-11 versions, eg: `{$ifndef NEW_ALEX} type TClassicStringDynArray = TArray<string>; TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray = TArray<TPermissionStatus>; {$endif}` And then get rid of the remaining `{$ifdef}`'s and use just the `NEW_ALEX`-based code by itself in all versions.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There's also the changes to the `PermissionService.RequestPermissions` that must be accomodated!

Comment: @FreddieBell the only thing I see different between them is naming. In your code, you use `PermissionRequest()` and `PermissionResult()` for Rio but use `DisplayRationale()` and `PermissionsResult()` for Alexandria. But the two versions have *identical* body codes, and their signatures are *identical* if you abstract the different parameter types with aliases. So, I see no reason to `IFDEF` the entire code they way you have, it should be greatly simplified.